# Is there a good alternative to Adobe Flash on Linux that's not a CPU hog?

Tags: google-chrome, flash, adobe

My CPU stays on 100 and sometimes drops to the high 90s when I'm using flash for Chrome and Firefox isn't much lower. I disabled the Pepper flash and enable hardware acceleration in `Chrome://flags` and it lowered it to the low 90s- high 80s, but that still seems a bit high and I've heard the only problem is most likely Adobe Flash itself.

Does anyone know of a good Linux alternative to Adobe Flash or are there more things you can do to reduce CPU? My processor is`AMD Sempron 145` if that's of any use.

Comment: [**GNU Gnash**](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnash/) ; package `gnash` (GNU Shockwave Flash (SWF) player).

Answer (score 3):

Quoted from [here](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/360557-weekend-project-open-source-alternatives-to-adobe-flash-on-linux)

> It will ultimately require two: **[Gnash](http://www.getgnash.org/)** and **[Lightspark](http://lightspark.github.io/)**. The two projects
>   cover different versions of the Flash specification; Gnash is the more
>   mature project, and supports Flash content up to version 8. Version 9
>   of Flash debuted sporting a rewritten version of ActionScript based on
>   an entirely different virtual machine model; Lightspark implements
>   this newer framework.

Download Gnash from http://www.getgnash.org/packages/

Download Lightspark from https://launchpad.net/lightspark/+download

To install Lightspark in Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install lightspark browser-plugin-lightspark
```

Read the [article](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/360557-weekend-project-open-source-alternatives-to-adobe-flash-on-linux) for more information.

To install gnash

```
 sudo apt-get install browser-plugin-gnash
```

---

**UPDATE:**

[Shumway](http://mozilla.github.io/shumway/) is an experimental web-native runtime implementation of the SWF file format. It is developed as a free and open source project sponsored by Mozilla Research. The project has two main goals.

Download the latest extension from [here](http://mozilla.github.io/shumway/extension/firefox/shumway.xpi)

[Also you can try](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/01/pepper-flash-alternative-to-adobe-flash.html) Pepper Flash Player which is maintained by Google, and is newer than Adobe Flash Player.

Installation:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:skunk/pepper-flash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pepflashplugin-installer
echo '. /usr/lib/pepflashplugin-installer/pepflashplayer.sh' | sudo tee -a /etc/chromium-browser/default
```

[source and more information found here](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/01/pepper-flash-alternative-to-adobe-flash.html)

Comment: I don't understand how to download them. The files are on my computer, what do I do next? Are there terminal commands I can do instead?

Comment: And neither of those packages have been updated in 2 years. Will I still be able to keep using them?

Comment: Maybe you'll ger fed of lightspark alone. anyway check the update how to install ightspark on ubuntu

Comment: I'm not having much success with anything outside of YouTube to work. Shame really that we have to depend on Adobe so much with flash.

Comment: you tried lightspark?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work too well with stuff other than YouTube.

Comment: Bad to know that

Comment: What kind of flash player do you use?

Comment: Adob flash badly... Check the edit in the answer

Comment: Dang, Shumway doesn't work too well either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23653/discussion-between-new-user-and-bighippo).